# Tensor Product Construction, Solution Set Condition.

Tags: category-theory

I am developing the basic properties of tensors, using categories. Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Fix $A, B\in R-Mod$ and define $K:R-Mod\rightarrow Set$ by $KC=\left \{ \beta :\left | A \right |\times \left | B \right |\rightarrow \left | C \right | \right \}$ where $\beta $ is bilinear.

I want to realize the tensor product $A\bigotimes _{R}B$ as a universal element. From there, the basic properties of tensors, including the hom-tensor adjunction follow readily. So, I need to show that $\left ( \ast \downarrow K \right )$ satisfies the solution set condition but I am having trouble showing that my choice works. Here is what I have so far:

Let the balanced map $\beta :A\times B\rightarrow C$ be given. Since $K$ preserves limits, and $R-Mod$ has pullbacks, there is an $s\in R-Mod$, a mono $v:s\rightarrow C$ and a $y:\ast \rightarrow Ks $ s.t. $Kv(y)=\beta $.

Now the arrow $y$ satisfies: if there is a mono $m:s'\rightarrow s$ and an arrow $f:\ast \rightarrow Ks'$s.t. $Km(f)=y$, then $m$ is an isomorphism. Taking $f=y$, $s'=$ span$\left \{ y (a,b)  \right \}$, and $m$ insertion, we see that we can in fact assume that $s=s_{y}= $span$\left \{ y(a,b)  \right \}$, which is the collection of all finite sums of the form $ \sum_{a,b} y \left ( a,b \right )$.

Final edit:

The cardinality of each $s_{y}$ is bounded by #$|R||A||B|$. The collection of all ordinals less than this is a small set. For each ordinal $\alpha \leq \text {#}|R||A||B|$, consider $S_{\alpha }$, the collection all objects $r$ in $R-Mod$ of the form span$\beta (a,b)$ where $\beta $ is a bilinear map $:\left | A \right |\times \left | B \right |\rightarrow \left | C \right |$ and #span$ \beta_(a,b)=\alpha $. This collection is a small set because the number of R-modules M with caridnality $\alpha$ is bounded by the cardnality of the set of functions $\left |M  \right |\times M\rightarrow \left | M \right |$ and $\left | R \right |\times \left | M \right |\rightarrow \left | M \right |$ Take $S=\left \{ \text {span} \left \{ \beta _{\alpha }(a,b) \right \} \right \}_{\alpha }$ over all $\alpha$ less than #$|R||A||B|$. Then $S$ is small and forms a solution set.

Comment: Please do not edit your question so often, as that results in it getting bumped on the main page and somewhat disrupts the site.

Comment: Given that it's not hard to construct the tensor product directly and prove that it represents bilinear maps (i.e. is a universal element), it's not really clear what your motivation is. But I will say that there are many formulations of / variations on the adjoint functor theorem, and it would be helpful to say exactly which formulation you're using. You might be intereseted in learning alternative formulations which might be more convenient, e.g. Mac Lane V.6, V.8 or the [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem) and references there.

Comment: If $K$ satisfies the solution set condition, it is representable.(I forget where this thm is in CW). From there, all properties of tensor product follow by easy calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality of $M$ is bounded by $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ((|R||A||B|)^n)$. This equals $\aleph_0 |R| |A| |B|$, but one does not have to use this cardinal numbers fact in order to get a solution set. Also, your set $S$ is not a set. It is only essentially small. For details, see also [SE/614461](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614461).